# Recover only one partition from system image

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, backup, windows-7-backup

Unfortunately, I need to format my HDD and restore it later to exactly the same state it was before.

My system ist like this:
Windows 7
1 SSD as the Windows System drive
1 HDD as Data storage

Now I did the built-in system image and put that on an external hard drive. Moreover, I have the Acronis TrueImage WD Edititon for recovery aswell.

My external drive isn't capable of holding the windows system image and a backup of only the HDD. Therefore, my question is:

Is it possible to recover only the HDD (not system-partition) using Acronis? It gives me that option but I'm really not sure whether that will totally recover ONLY the HDD.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Formating your HDD and restoring it to exactly its previous state ? What's the point of doing such a thing ?

Comment: Instaalling Linux on the free space. Linux doesn't recognize Windows' partition and therefore overwrites it. Thus, I need to install Linux on the HDD first and then recover the Windows data.